# How to improve Levenberg-Marquardt's method for polynomial curve fitting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression, gradient-descent

Some weeks ago I started coding the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm from scratch in Matlab. I'm interested in the polynomial fitting of the data but I haven't been able to achieve the level of accuracy I would like. I'm using a fifth order polynomial after I tried other polynomials and it seemed to be the best option. The algorithm always converges to the same function minimization no matter what improvements I try to implement. So far, I have unsuccessfully added the following features:

- Geodesic acceleration term as a second order correction
- Delayed gratification for updating the damping parameter
- Gain factor to get closer to the Gauss-Newton direction or 
  the steepest descent direction depending on the iteration.
- Central differences and forward differences for the finite difference method

I don't have experience in nonlinear least squares, so I don't know if there is a way to minimize the residual even more or if there isn't more room for improvement with this method. I attach below an image of the behavior of the polynomial for the last iterations. If I run the code for more iterations, the curve ends up not changing from iteration to iteration. As it is observed, there is a good fit from time = 0 to time = 12. But I'm not able to fix the behavior of the function from time = 12 to time = 20. Any help will be very appreciated.

[image: polynomial fitting]

Comment: 1) By "polynomial fitting" do you mean fitting the coefficients of a fixed polynomial? E.g. fitting $a,b,c$ for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$? 2) What loss function are you using? Squared error?

Comment: @user20160 That's correct. I'm fitting the coefficients of $f(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex$ and using squared error.